# Redirect multiple subdomains to their https subdomains - nginx

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I currently have multiple reverse proxies on sites-enabled on nginx that I would like to redirect all http traffic to https, basically and for simplistic reasons, this can be archive by using a catch-all server block on a separate configuration.

The problem lies on the return directive.....I do not how to write it

Consider the following

nginx/sites-enabled/site_a.conf,site_b.conf,site_c.conf

these sites can be accessed on:

```
1) a.localhost
2) b.localhost
3) c.localhost
```

I want to create a catch-all solution that will listen on port 80 and redirect

`http://a.localhost => https://a.localhost`

`http://b.localhost => https://b.localhost`

`http://c.localhost => https://c.localhost`

```
#Http subdomains redirect
server {
    listen      80 reuseport;
    listen      [::]:80 reuseport;
    server_name .localhost;
    return      301 ? ? ? ? ? ? # what goes here
}
```

Comment: Try: `return 301 https://$host$request_uri;` - see [the list of Nginx variables](http://nginx.org/en/docs/varindex.html)

Comment: Thanks, this works! I played around the variables, but was writing https://$host.localhost; instead of https://$host$request_uri;